# Addig a SQL Database to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to link my ASP.Net MVC (VS2013) to my SQL Server (SQL Server 2014 Mgt Studio) but failing!  This is the code I have set up but i either get an 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException'on the ResultsView or the data from the table doesnt' show up.  Any help would be much appreciated - I have attached my code below:

Model:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

   namespace GlobalMetricsTest2.Models
    {
        public class GMUSALong
        {
            public virtual int BID { get; set; }
            public virtual string BMetrics { get; set; }
            public virtual string BTopic { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Context:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using GlobalMetricsTest2.Models;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace GlobalMetricsTest2.DAL
    {
        public class GMUSALongContext : DbContext
        {

            public DbSet<GMUSALong> GMTest { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using GlobalMetricsTest2.DAL;
    using GlobalMetricsTest2.Models;

    namespace GlobalMetricsTest2.Controllers
    {
        public class GMUSALongController : Controller
        {
            private GMUSALongContext db = new GMUSALongContext();

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var advItems = db.GMTest;
                return View(advItems.ToList());


            }
        }
    }
```

View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<GlobalMetricsTest2.Models.GMUSALong>


    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Metrics</th>
            <th>Topic</th>

        </tr>

    @foreach (GlobalMetricsTest2.Models.GMUSALong item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.BID:</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BMetrics)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BTopic)</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: post your entityframework section from web.config

Comment: What does your connection string look like in web.config?

Comment: What is the exact name of your table in your database, GMUSALongs?  Also, you'll going to have to annotate the primary key if its named BID, by default entity framework expects ID or GMUSALongID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the beginner perspective, I would recommend you try another approach.  Create your database table(s) as you desire.  Then create a templated MVC project by navigating to New -> Project, select ASP.NET Web Application.  You will be prompted with further options, select 'MVC'.  This will give you a nice template example that you can reference for any MVC questions.  Creating new project and adding MVC 5 with NUGET will start a cleaner example but requires more steps.

Now that you have your website created.  Right click on your 'Models' folder, Add -> New Item, select ADO.NET Entity Data Model, you will be prompted with more options, select 'Code First from database, provide your database connection information, and select which objects you'd like imported.  At this point you should have a functional data Context with all the required annotations assigned to non-standard naming conventions.

Now right-click on your 'Views' folder, Add -> 'New Scaffolded Item', select 'MVC 5 View', name your view (I'd recommend your model's name + 'View'), select which model you'd like to use, choose which type of screen you'd like to create, this would be 'List'.  Once created you'll have a nice standard example of all the pieces you are trying to learn.  Once you've gained the knowledge you need, you can make minor tweaks to this process to rapidly create highly functional screens for your site.

http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview

Comment: Thanks for this - for some reason I get an "Server Error in '/' Application" every time I debug - the browser says it can't locate the requested URL?  Otherwise the coding looks much better....

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your routes, make sure that you have a Global.aspx that calls RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);  You might want to check the windows event viewer, this could also happen for other less obvious reasons.

Comment: Firstly - thanks so much for that advice - it was really useful way to understand MVC better.  I added the "Controller" code I outlined in my original question and it seem it worked.  Thanks again for your time